# thread-safe cache for sparse, lazy, immutable arrays

Tags: c, caching, immutability, glib, sparse-array

I have an application that involves a collection of arrays which can be very large (indices up to the maximum value of an `int`), but which are *lazy* - their contents are calculated on the fly and are not actually known until requested.  The arrays are also *immutable* - the value of each element of each array is constant throughout the life of the program.  The arrays are *sparse* in the sense that often only a small subset of all array elements are ever requested (the arrays do not contain large blocks of zeros and are not "sparse" in that sense.)

Looking up (and possibly calculating in the process) an array element can be expensive, so I want to add a caching layer.  The cache should implement the following interface:

```
void point_cache_store (gpointer data, gsize idx, gdouble value);
gdouble point_cache_fetch (gpointer data, gsize idx);
```

where `data` serves as a unique handle for each array (there can be many of these).  `point_cache_fetch()` should return the `value` argument passed to `point_cache_store()` with the same `data` and `idx` arguments, or indicate a cache miss by returning the special value `DATUM_UNKNOWN_VALUE` (the caller will never call `point_cache_store` with `DATUM_UNKNOWN_VALUE`).

The question is: **how can I implement `point_cache_fetch()` and `point_cache_store()`**?  (They are currently no-op stubs.)

Points to consider:

- The cache implementation must be thread-safe.  Several threads are running simultaneously and any of these can call `point_cache_store()` or `point_cache_fetch()` with any `data` or `idx` arguments.
- The cache truly is a cache; it's always OK for `point_cache_fetch()` to return `DATUM_UNKNOWN_VALUE`, even if it once knew that value.  The caller will just perform an ordinary lookup in that case.
- Remember, the arrays are immutable - for given `data` and `idx` arguments, the caller will always provide the same `value` argument.

I realize that there are many ways to do this and that there are tradeoffs involved.  For this question, though, I am going to evaluate answers by one very specific criterion: whether they improve performance in one particular benchmark in the application that inspired the question.  If you want to go the extra mile and run the benchmark yourself, here is how to do it:

```
git clone git://github.com/gbenison/starparse
git clone git://github.com/gbenison/burrow-owl.git -b point-cache-base
```

The functions `point_cache_fetch()` and `point_cache_store()` are found in "burrow/spectrum/point_cache.c".  The relevant benchmark is "benchmarks/b_cache".

Comment: If the cache cache can forget items, then your cache interface need to add a way to free items returned from the cache.

Comment: @sbridges What's there to free?  `point_cache_fetch` just returns a `double`.

Comment: What is the width of gsize?  I assume that gpointer is a pointer and gdouble is a double?

Comment: @jonathanLeonard On most platforms, I think that yes, a gdouble is just a double and a gpointer is just a pointer.  The names come from [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Basic-Types.html) and are supposed to be part of a platform-independent set of types.  `gsize` is `unsigned long`

Comment: What is the distribution of idxs?  I know you said the arrays are sparse but are the used elements roughly evenly distributed?

Comment: @jonathan Unfortunately that varies - for some arrays, the access pattern will tend to cover short, contiguous blocks, but for others, the pattern will be strided (e.g. access every 1000th element).  It's on the to do list to instrument the code better to get some measurements of actual access patterns.

Comment: Are you sure you need a cache? You state "contents are calculated on the fly and are not actually known until requested", if the data is predictably reused then a cache may be useful, but that does not seem to be the case with your information.

Comment: @dtyree No, I am not sure that in all use cases, the cache will be a net win vs. always recalculating the values; I do think that sometimes it will.  It probably varies quite a bit between use cases.  I do need to collect more data on how often the same values are fetched.

Comment: I would recommend either a b-tree or red-black tree. I'm sure you can find implementations of these in C.

Answer (score 0):

A "very large sparse lazy array"? Sounds like you need a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

From your `point_cache_fetch` function prototype and all through your question, I am confused about whether your cached values are doubles or immutable arrays.

I'm not going to provide an implementation, as this is not a 'coding challenge' website. You should try to find and reuse existing libraries of threadsafe hashtables and compare their performance for your specific needs.

Comment: I agree with Eldritch Conundrum on the hashmap. A storage entity that held the data while offering callback functions for specific calculations could suit the problem.

Comment: @eldritchconundrum First of all, cool name.  Second - what's being cached are immutable arrays of doubles.

Comment: Know of any good threadsafe hashtable libraries in C?  Do they take advantage of immutability somehow?

Comment: I see.. the large sparse lazy arrays are what's cached. Then you should consider replacing them by hash tables. So, you'd have a hash table of hash tables. Maybe you can somehow combine `data` and `idx` so that you end up with only one hash table.

Comment: I think you shouldn't insist on taking advantage of immutability here. Your arrays are lazily initialized, which makes them... actually mutable.